# How do I pass parameters to a jar file at the time of execution?

Tags: jar

How do I pass parameters to a JAR file at the time of execution?

Answer (score 175):

To pass arguments to the jar:

```
java -jar myjar.jar one two
```

You can access them in the main() method of "Main-Class" (mentioned in the `manifest.mf` file of a JAR).

```
String one = args[0];  
String two = args[1];
```

Answer (score 46):

The [JAVA Documentation says](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/tools/jar.html#GUID-51C11B76-D9F6-4BC2-A805-3C847E857867):

> java [ options ] -jar file.jar [
>   argument ... ]

and

> ... Non-option arguments after the
>   class name or JAR file name are passed
>   to the main function...

Maybe you have to put the arguments in single quotes.

Answer (score 18):

You can do it with something like this, so if no arguments are specified it will continue anyway:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        String one = args[0];
        String two = args[1];
    }
    catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
        System.out.println("ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException caught");
    }
    finally {

    }
}
```

And then launch the application:

```
java -jar myapp.jar arg1 arg2
```

Comment: You should never use exceptions to steer your code. Instead, you should check the length of the array before acessing it!

Comment: Well, if the program must ALWAYS have one or more parameters, having none is IMHO a legitimate case for using an exception.

Answer (score 8):

```
java [ options ] -jar file.jar [ argument ... ]
```

if you need to pass the log4j properties file use the below option

```
-Dlog4j.configurationFile=directory/file.xml


java -Dlog4j.configurationFile=directory/file.xml -jar <JAR FILE> [arguments ...]
```

Answer (score 2):

Incase arguments have spaces in it, you can pass like shown below.

```
java -jar myjar.jar 'first argument' 'second argument'
```