# Executing jar with file names as arguments

Tags: jar

I want to run a jar with file names as arguments. for eg.

**java -jar xyz.jar "C:\files"**  where "C:\files" directory contains all the files.

Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

What does the main class in the xyz.jar do?

Does it main method accept file names as arguments?

Does it understand that if the argument is a directory name, it needs to get the list of files in the directory and perform the operation on them instead?

Comment: xyz.jar is a simple swing application, that accepts simple .gif file to be displayed in swing application.

Comment: and yes the main method has the functionality to accept the directory as arguments

Comment: If this is the case, look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/456636/passing-parameters-to-jar-file . Good luck!