# Execute a .jar file using shell script

Tags: java, linux, bash, jar, domo

I want to execute a jar file of DOMO CLI from a shell script. The jar file itself has some functions which I want to call after I call the main jar file. The problem which I am facing is that after it executes the jar file, I am not able to pass the additional commands to execute inside that jar through a shell script. It just stops after calling jar and doesn't take further commands. Can anyone please help? Below is the code I am calling from a shell script.

```
java -jar XX.jar
```

The commands are as below which follow the above jar. So once we enter into the above jar we have to execute the below commands one after the other. I am not sure how to achieve this through a shell script.

```
connect -s X.domo.com -t Ysssss

upload-dataset -a -i dhdhdhdh -f /prehdfs/dev/comres/herm/data/yyyy.csv
```

Comment: `java -jar XX.jar &` will start the `java` process and run it in the background (so your other commands will then execute).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch it does start the java process but it doesn't run the commands after that. It is showing the blank screen thereafter.    I have executed like below:                                                                                               
   java -jar XX.jar & 

connect -s X.domo.com -t Ysssss

Comment: Are those lines are meant to be supplied on standard in to the java process? If so, take a look at [expect](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/expect-command-in-linux-with-examples/).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch : I don't see any `&` in the post!

Comment: @yogesh: In what way does the Java program expect the additional input? By command line, via stdin, via some configuration file .... ?

Comment: @user1934428 yes through command line, I have to run these additional commands like connect, upload etc after executing jar. But these have to be run in shell script. Please suggest.

Comment: So why don't you just add the additional parameters on the command line? `java -jar XX.jar PARAMETER1 PARAMETER2 ....`.

Comment: @user1934428 that doesn't work either. I have tried this already. It doesnt take those parameters.

Comment: @Yogesh : From this, I would conclude that the Java program is not designed to access `argv`. BTW, this problem has already been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456636/how-do-i-pass-parameters-to-a-jar-file-at-the-time-of-execution)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using pipes and inputs.
When you execute above it runs it under a child shell.

You may try below format if not tried already

```
$ (echo "connect -s X.domo.com -t Ysssss" && cat) | java -jar XX.jar
```

Comment: The code you provided works but if I try to run the another code together, it fails to execute. I am executing code like this:     (echo "connect -s X.domo.com -t Ysssss" && upload-dataset -a -i dhdhdhdh -f /prehdfs/dev/comres/herm/data/yyyy.csv && cat) | java -jar XX.jar   .... It gives error "No such file or directory" on /prehdfs/dev/comres/herm/data/yyyy.csv. Any suggestions?

Comment: it is working only to run 1 command, but if more than 1 needs to be run, it is giving error.

Comment: What is the output of $ls -alt  /prehdfs/dev/comres/herm/data/yyyy.csv

Answer (score 0):

If you can reference a file in your use case, you could put your commands in a file.

File: list_my_datasets.domo

```
connect -t ... -s ...
list-dataset
quit
```

then run the command:

```
java -jar domoUtil.jar -script list_my_datasets.domo > datasets
```

I wanted the data from it so I piped to a file (where I had to grep what I wanted), but you would omit that I believe, unless it has some output you'd want to check. I haven't tested with the upload command, but I would hope any commands substituted or added to the example work similarly.

[Domo docs on scripting](https://knowledge.domo.com/Administer/Other_Administrative_Tools/Command_Line_Interface_(CLI)_Tool#Scripting)