# Facing issue in extracting value from nested jsonArray

Tags: java, rest-assured-jsonpath

I know a similar question has been posted, however, the answer didn't work for me.

I am new to this RestAssured.I want to get the 'uuid' value if categories equals to 'FUNGI' and feature->features conatains 'VRA'.This is my sample json:

```
[{
      "uuid":"e223d29b-499b-b58b-995e-654bef1aab03",
      "categories":[
         {
            "uuid":"89d1c022-4453-5f6b-883c-46730d429b2a",
            "name":"FERTI"
         }
      ],
      "minRateSi":0.0
   },
   {
      "uuid":"93015a1b-76ac-2ca3-2bbc-5ae5480962c2",
      "categories":[
         {
            "uuid":"61c951b1-3e47-f0a0-80d8-3d43efa339fb",
            "name":"FUNGI"
         }
      ],
      "minRateSi":0.0,
      "maxRateSi":7.5E-8,
      "features":[
         {
            "id":"9b4ee6b2-ae2d-6c9a-af77-08a4b749031f",
            "vraMinRate":2.0E-8,
            "features":[
               "VRA"
            ]
         },
         {
            "id":"ec0d0f52-dd71-ebb9-0a39-831768fe4490",
            "vraMinRateSi":3.0E-8,
            "features":[
               "VRA"
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "uuid":"38290452-4937-4f33-c54d-7f502b84ed99",
      "categories":[
         {
            "uuid":"2c9d8cc0-01bc-899d-6782-cf412e90fd78",
            "name":"FUNGI"
         }
      ],
      "maxRateSi":1.0E-7,
      "features":[
         {
            "id":"9b4ee6b2-ae2d-6c9a-af77-08a4b749031f",
            "vraMinRateSi":6.5E-8
         },
         {
            "cropUuid":"ec0d0f52-dd71-ebb9-0a39-831768fe4490",
            "vraMinRateSi":5.0E-8
         }
      ]}]
```

Comment: You have two `uuid` which one are you trying to get? the nested one inside `category` or the one outside `category`?

Comment: uuid outside the category

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Woo , okay your case was pretty hard to break down, but as far as you know how to use `JSONArray` and `JSONObject` classes you will be fine.

First of all let me mention how you should approach this kind of scenarios.

---

I prefer using an online **JSON Formatter** [like this one](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) simply paste your `JSON` payload and you will be able to tell whether to use `JSONObject` or `JSONArray`.

Please take a note here, and check out [how to parse json payloads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

This code will work for you, although you need to find out the **logic** behind it and implement **JSON parsing** accordingly in your future cases.

```java
//declaring your payload
String myJsonPayload = "[{\r\n" + "      \"uuid\":\"e223d29b-499b-b58b-995e-654bef1aab03\",\r\n" +
 "      \"categories\":[\r\n" + "         {\r\n" +
 "            \"uuid\":\"89d1c022-4453-5f6b-883c-46730d429b2a\",\r\n" +
 "            \"name\":\"FERTI\"\r\n" + "         }\r\n" + "      ],\r\n" +
 "      \"minRateSi\":0.0\r\n" + "   },\r\n" + "   {\r\n" +
 "      \"uuid\":\"93015a1b-76ac-2ca3-2bbc-5ae5480962c2\",\r\n" + "      \"categories\":[\r\n" +
 "         {\r\n" + "            \"uuid\":\"61c951b1-3e47-f0a0-80d8-3d43efa339fb\",\r\n" +
 "            \"name\":\"FUNGI\"\r\n" + "         }\r\n" + "      ],\r\n" +
 "      \"minRateSi\":0.0,\r\n" + "      \"maxRateSi\":7.5E-8,\r\n" + "      \"features\":[\r\n" +
 "         {\r\n" + "            \"id\":\"9b4ee6b2-ae2d-6c9a-af77-08a4b749031f\",\r\n" +
 "            \"vraMinRate\":2.0E-8,\r\n" + "            \"features\":[\r\n" +
 "               \"VRA\"\r\n" + "            ]\r\n" + "         },\r\n" + "         {\r\n" +
 "            \"id\":\"ec0d0f52-dd71-ebb9-0a39-831768fe4490\",\r\n" +
 "            \"vraMinRateSi\":3.0E-8,\r\n" + "            \"features\":[\r\n" +
 "               \"VRA\"\r\n" + "            ]\r\n" + "         }\r\n" + "      ]\r\n" + "   },\r\n" +
 "   {\r\n" + "      \"uuid\":\"38290452-4937-4f33-c54d-7f502b84ed99\",\r\n" +
 "      \"categories\":[\r\n" + "         {\r\n" +
 "            \"uuid\":\"2c9d8cc0-01bc-899d-6782-cf412e90fd78\",\r\n" +
 "            \"name\":\"FUNGI\"\r\n" + "         }\r\n" + "      ],\r\n" +
 "      \"maxRateSi\":1.0E-7,\r\n" + "      \"features\":[\r\n" + "         {\r\n" +
 "            \"id\":\"9b4ee6b2-ae2d-6c9a-af77-08a4b749031f\",\r\n" +
 "            \"vraMinRateSi\":6.5E-8\r\n" + "         },\r\n" + "         {\r\n" +
 "            \"cropUuid\":\"ec0d0f52-dd71-ebb9-0a39-831768fe4490\",\r\n" +
 "            \"vraMinRateSi\":5.0E-8\r\n" + "         }\r\n" + "      ]}]";

JSONArray json = new JSONArray(myJsonPayload);
System.out.println(json);

for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {
 JSONObject object = (JSONObject) json.get(i);
 // System.out.println(object); // you have each JSONObject { } contained in the
 // Outer JSONArray [ ]
 //Getting both uuid's since you didn't answer which one.
 String uuid = object.getString("uuid");
 System.out.println("\n\n Next Object - Outer UUID: " + uuid);
 JSONArray categories = object.getJSONArray("categories");
 System.out.println(categories);
 if (((JSONObject) categories.get(0)).getString("name").equalsIgnoreCase("fungi")) {
  System.out.println("\nFUNGI found!:\n");
  //Getting the inner UUID
  String uuidOfFungi = ((JSONObject) categories.get(0)).getString("uuid");
  System.out.println("Inner UUID: " + uuidOfFungi);
 } else {
  System.out.println("\nFUNGI NOT FOUND (ABORTING):\n");
 }


 // Getting Features:
 try {
  JSONArray featuresObject = object.getJSONArray("features");

  for (int index = 0; index < featuresObject.length(); index++) {
   try {
    JSONObject features = featuresObject.getJSONObject(index);
    //Getting VRA
    String vraFeatues = features.getJSONArray("features").getString(0);

   } catch (JSONException e) {
    System.out.println("No inner JSONArray in features JSONObject");
   }
  }


 } catch (JSONException e) {
  System.out.println("JSON OBJECT " + i + " HAS NO FEATURES ARRAY");
 }


}
```

---

Depending again on your use-case it's up to you how you will get the `JSON` payload into your program.

- [Getting it from remote URL using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308554/simplest-way-to-read-json-from-a-url-in-java/4308662)
- [Passing it as an argument on `java -jar` execution time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456636/how-do-i-pass-parameters-to-a-jar-file-at-the-time-of-execution) , which i don't really recommend

Either case, modifications need to be done in order to initialize `myJsonPayload` accordingly.

Hope it helped!

Comment: Thank you Phill for the response. I got an idea, now I can tweak the logic accordingly.